# Grammar or Gmara?

Tags: talmud-gemara, grammar-dikduk

I recently reviewed Rashi commentaries on the word "כי" in Torah, he quotes several times this Gemara (one of the occurences is in Rosh Hashana 3a):

> דאמר ריש לקיש: כי משמש בארבע לשונות: אי, דילמא, אלא, דהא.‏
>
> in accordance with the dictum of Resh Lakish; for Resh Lakish said, Ki has four significations - 'if', 'perhaps', 'but' 'for'.(Soncino's translation)

Rashi on Gemara explains this widely.
When I checked sifre shorashim Radak and R.I. Ibn G'anach. They explain the word ki without mentioning the Gemara.
I asked myself if the Statement of Resh Lakish is only mnemonic, witch is not shown as "Haatakat Shmua"; if so, I am not surprised by the "omission". Perhaps Resh Lakish have a "key" to understand halachot in verses, as a Kabala from generations. So it is strange that Rishonim do not show that they comply with Resh Lakish.
When we look the examples, obviously nothing is contradictory with R.L. But we see that Rashi is being made to refer to Resh Lakish, e.g. when he say that "כי" is "אשר", Rashi says that "אשר" is included in "אי"‎<sup>[1]</sup>. It is important for him, but not for Radak and R.I. Ibn G'anach. **What is the difference?**

---

[1] e.g. Rashi Rosh Hashana 3a: ...‏ וכל המשמשין במקום כאשר ובמקום אשר כולן לשון אם הם 
‏
 See also Rashi Gittin 90a ...וכל כי הנפתרים בלשון כאשר כמו והיה כי יביאך וכל אלו שאין אתה יכול לפותרו בלשון אם דהא ודאי יביאך וכן כי תבואו אל הארץ כי בא סוס פרעה כי תרבו ופריתם בארץ כולן לשון דהא הן נפתרים במדרש  סיפרא וסיפרי עשה מצוה זו שבשבילה תכנס לארץ
...‏"

Comment: My bad, I thought you meant they didn't put R.L as a source. Anyway. Radak does bring up the fact that Ki has several meanings [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43656&st=&pgnum=165&hilite=). And I still believe Rashi prefers to stick to 'Leshon Talmud' as a way of teaching. In addition,  I saw that Hebrew Grammar didn't 'pass on', Ba'alai Meshorah used their own insight to figure out Hebrew (where it is possible, obviously not regarding the Mesorah part of it). Words that are considered 'exception' might belong to a bigger rule. We have different opinion about shorashim.

Comment: `I asked myself if the Statement [sic] of Resh Lakish is only mnemonic, witch [sic] is not shown as "Haatakat Shmua";` What is this supposed to mean? || `But we see that Rashi is being made to refer to Resh Lakish` I someone making Rashi do something? What are you trying to say? || This question is very difficult to decipher. Are you asking why certain grammarians don't mention a Gemara that agrees with them, while others do? How could anyone possibly know what motivated their respective literary styles?

Comment: @mevaqesh this means that RL can make a job like a grammarian,  or is transmitting a chazal

Comment: I dont understand. Are you asking the source for the statement of RL? Are you asking why some grammarians disagree with him? Are you asking why some agree with him, but don't mention his name, in relating the position? Something else? If the first or third, how could anyone answer this?